# Сервис CUPS не запускает печать

Tags: linux, принтер, cups

помогите с решение проблемы решил я установить Linux все прошло успешно но после установки драйвером пошли ошибки то есть ОС видит принтер но задание отказывается принимать.

```html
   
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] libusb_get_device_list=7
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18402 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Samsung_SCX_3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Samsung_SCX_3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Gray.None.600dpi...)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.NothingMatched:nothing matched expression \'Gray.None.600dpi,Gray.None.*,Gray.*.600dpi,Gray.*.*,*\'
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Failed to get profile filename for cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: no profiles specified in PPD
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: ICC Profile: None
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[12.500000 12.500000 12.500000 12.500000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@kali\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.3op2\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[18]=\"LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_SCX-3400_Series.ppd\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[20]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[21]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[22]=\"DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_INFO=Samsung SCX-3400 Series\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[25]=\"PRINTER=Samsung_SCX-3400_Series\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[26]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[27]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[28]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] envp[29]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Start rendering...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Processing page 1...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Operand stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] true   (/tmp/gs_50XaDc)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Execution stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Dictionary stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] --dict:740/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:320/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Current allocation mode is local
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Rendering completed
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18403 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Switching USB device configuration: 0 -> 1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,FWV,PIC,DCU,EXT;MDL:SCX-3400 Series;CLS:PRINTER;MODE:SCN,SPL3,R000105;STATUS:MPS; Device URI: usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Device protocol: 2
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Отправка данных на принтер.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Sent 0 bytes...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] Resetting printer.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18406 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] End of messages
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state=3(idle)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state-message="Отправка данных на принтер."
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:23 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state-reasons=none
E [11/Sep/2021:21:33:37 +0300] [Job 3] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] The following messages were recorded from 21:33:24 to 21:33:47
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Unloading...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Loading attributes...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Job restarted by user.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] time-at-processing=1631385217
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] 3 filters for job:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] rastertospl (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/Samsung_SCX-3400_Series, cost 0)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] job-sheets=none,none
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[0]="Samsung_SCX-3400_Series"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[1]="3"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[2]="phingziry"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[3]="Без имени 1"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[4]="1"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[5]="PageSize=A4 MediaType=None JCLDarkness=NORMAL TonerSaveMode=Standard number-up=1 noJCLSkipBlankPages noCollate EdgeControl=Normal Quality=600dpi InputSlot=Auto job-uuid=urn:uuid:293bb685-d9bf-35f7-7eb2-8e3b5c71ec09 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1631385193 time-at-processing=1631385217"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00003-001"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@kali"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.3op2"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[19]="LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_SCX-3400_Series.ppd"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Samsung SCX-3400 Series"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[26]="PRINTER=Samsung_SCX-3400_Series"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 18426)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 18427)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl (PID 18428)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 18429)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Restarted by "phingziry".
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18428 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl) stopped with status 127 (File too large)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Samsung_SCX-3400_Series: error while loading shared libraries: libcupsimage.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Loaded 98 quirks.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] OUTFORMAT=\"<none>\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertospl; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] libusb_get_device_list=7
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18426 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Samsung_SCX_3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Samsung_SCX_3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Gray.None.600dpi...)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.NothingMatched:nothing matched expression \'Gray.None.600dpi,Gray.None.*,Gray.*.600dpi,Gray.*.*,*\'
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Failed to get profile filename for cups-Samsung_SCX-3400_Series
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: no profiles specified in PPD
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Color Manager: ICC Profile: None
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[12.500000 12.500000 12.500000 12.500000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@kali\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.3op2\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[18]=\"LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Samsung_SCX-3400_Series.ppd\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[20]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[21]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[22]=\"DEVICE_URI=usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_INFO=Samsung SCX-3400 Series\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[25]=\"PRINTER=Samsung_SCX-3400_Series\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[26]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[27]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[28]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] envp[29]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Start rendering...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Processing page 1...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Operand stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] true   (/tmp/gs_DV2cM2)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Execution stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Dictionary stack:
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] --dict:740/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:320/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Current allocation mode is local
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Rendering completed
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18427 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Switching USB device configuration: 0 -> 1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,FWV,PIC,DCU,EXT;MDL:SCX-3400 Series;CLS:PRINTER;MODE:SCN,SPL3,R000105;STATUS:MPS; Device URI: usb://Samsung/SCX-3400%20Series?serial=Z6ZVB8KF1C014LA&interface=1
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Device protocol: 2
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Отправка данных на принтер.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Sent 0 bytes...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] Resetting printer.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] PID 18429 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] End of messages
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state=3(idle)
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state-message="Отправка данных на принтер."
D [11/Sep/2021:21:33:47 +0300] [Job 3] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Comment: возможно недообновился где-то

Comment: драйвер правильнойц разрядности?

Comment: В архиве были только install.sh, install_scanner, install_printer

Comment: В самом сервисе пишет "filter failed"

Comment: в этом архиве https://support.hp.com/ru-ru/drivers/selfservice/samsung-scx-3400-laser-multifunction-printer-series/17156995? этот правильный если что)

Comment: "filter failed" это понятно, но возможно gs обновился, а купс нет

Comment: Переустановил драйвера все равно все так же, а что такое gs?

Comment: `GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`  штука, которая у вас падает. Кстати какой дистрибутив?

Comment: Kali Linux рабочая среда gnome

Comment: Не думаю, что у кали всё хорошо с пакетами для печати. Вернее, что их отлично тестируют.